# Tomcat 7.0.82 Release for Restcomm Sip Servlets

Tags: sip, restcomm

We are using Restcomm as a sip stack for one of our applications. We would like to be able to deploy in Tomcat 7.0.82 for security fixes, but I am unable to build the jars against this version. This is the error that I receive:

```
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.701s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 10 09:56:38 EST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 63M/859M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project sip-servlets-catalina-7: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\npocta\workspace\sip-servlets-release-2.0.0.FINAL\containers\sip-servlets-catalina-7\src\main\java\org\mobicents\servlet\sip\catalina\security\authentication\DigestAuthenticator.java:[44,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\npocta\workspace\sip-servlets-release-2.0.0.FINAL\containers\sip-servlets-catalina-7\src\main\java\org\mobicents\servlet\sip\catalina\security\authentication\DigestAuthenticator.java:[73,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\npocta\workspace\sip-servlets-release-2.0.0.FINAL\containers\sip-servlets-catalina-7\src\main\java\org\mobicents\servlet\sip\catalina\security\authentication\DigestAuthenticator.java:[73,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\npocta\workspace\sip-servlets-release-2.0.0.FINAL\containers\sip-servlets-catalina-7\src\main\java\org\mobicents\servlet\sip\catalina\SipStandardManager.java:[184,68] error: incompatible types: SipStandardManager cannot be converted to PropertyChangeListener
[ERROR] \Users\npocta\workspace\sip-servlets-release-2.0.0.FINAL\containers\sip-servlets-catalina-7\src\main\java\org\mobicents\servlet\sip\catalina\SipStandardManager.java:[194,65] error: incompatible types: SipStandardManager cannot be converted to PropertyChangeListener`
```

My specific question is this: Are there plans in the future to make the sip servlets compatible with this version and/or does such a build already exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for future plans for an off-site project or product, and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. For questions related to that product or project, contact them directly via their web site. We are not support or planning for off-site resources.

Comment: @whitehotsteel can you please update the question with some more details as to how you're trying to build the project? i'm not sure the specific error logs you have shared are somehow related to just the tomcat version change.